# Best way to order across associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 models:

```
class Post
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end

class User
  has_many :comments
end
```

Now in the controller, I'd like to call @post.comments and order these comments by user.postcode. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
class Post
  has_many :comments, :order => "user.postcode"
end
```

I also tried:

```
class Comment
  def order_by_user_postcode
    includes(:user).order("user.postcode ASC")
  end
end

class PostsController
  @post.comments.order_by_user_postcode
end
```

which results in

```
undefined method for ActiveRecord::Relation
```

How can I write a method to chain to @post.comments to sort by user.postcode?

Comment: try `joins(:user).order("users.postcode")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must order:

```
has_many :comments, :order => "users.postcode"
```

Table name is users not user.

The second option:

You must implement the method like class method (or scope), not instance method

```
 def self.order_by_user_postcode
   joins(:user).order("users.postcode ASC")
 end
```

or scope:

```
scope :order_by_user_postcode, joins(:user).order("users.postcode ASC")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried the first option, which would be my preferred alternative. Got an error: `PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "users": SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."post.id" = 1 ORDER BY users.postcode  ASC. It seems like the order option on the association does not do the inner join?

Comment: can you post the query?? The users must be in the query if you want to order by "users.postcode"

Comment: This is the query, it doesn't seem to do an inner join and I don't know how I can pass in the inner join on the has_many method: `SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."post_id" = 1 ORDER BY user.postcode ASC`